# Use rxjs/Typescript to map an array inside a response from an external API

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am new to Typescript/Javascript and I am trying to get to the grips with the potential of rxjs.  I use this code

```
return this.http.get<IXenoCantoResponse>(`${this.corsAnywhereUrl}${this.xenoCantoApiBaseUrl}${this.formatSearchTerm(searchTerm)}${this.recordingLength}`)
  .pipe(
    map(o => ({
      numRecordings: o.numRecordings,
      numSpecies: o.numSpecies,
      page: o.page,
      numPages: o.numPages,
      recordings: o.recordings
    }))
  );
```

to map the response from a public API to an interface, `IXenoCanto`:

```
export interface IXenoCantoResponse {
    numRecordings: string;
    numSpecies: string;
    page: string;
    numPages: string;
    recordings: [];
  }
```

It is actually the `recordings[]` that I am interested in.  In subsequent code, I use the fields in this array to construct an url and add it to yet another object:

```
data.forEach((element, index) => {
  let sub = element.sono['full'].substr(0, this.getPosition(element.sono['full'], '\/', 6));
  urls.push({
    id: index + 1,
    url: `${sub}${element['file-name']}`
  });

});

export interface IVoice {
  id: number;
  url: string;
}
```

While it is true that this code does the job, I have been attempting to make it more effiently.

I wonder if it is possible to map the recordings `any[]` response straight to a `IVoice[]` in my initial map code.  So I have tried changing the IXenoCantoResponse interface like so:

```
export interface IXenoCantoResponse {
    numRecordings: string;
    numSpecies: string;
    page: string;
    numPages: string;
    recordings: IVoice[]
    // recordings: [];
  }
```

And then I can try to map the `[]` repsonse to the `IVoice[]` directly, something like this:

```
return this.http.get<IXenoCantoResponse>(`${this.corsAnywhereUrl}${this.xenoCantoApiBaseUrl}${this.formatSearchTerm(searchTerm)}${this.recordingLength}`)
      .pipe(
        map(o => ({
          numRecordings: o.numRecordings,
          numSpecies: o.numSpecies,
          page: o.page,
          numPages: o.numPages,
          recordings: o.recordings.map((element, index) => {

              id: index + 1,
              url: `${element.sono['full'].substr(0, this.getPosition(element.sono['full'], '\/', 6))}${element['file-name']}`
          }
          });
        }))
      );
```

I have so far been unable to get the second approach to work.  Is it possible to do this?  I think the problem lies in how to setup the `map` operator with an array object.  Is this right and can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

Each object in the recordings array mentioned above has the following format:

```
        {
            "id": "477551",
            "gen": "Troglodytes",
            "sp": "troglodytes",
            "ssp": "troglodytes",
            "en": "Eurasian Wren",
            "rec": "\u00c9tienne Leroy",
            "cnt": "Poland",
            "loc": "Hajn\u00f3wka, hajnowski, podlaskie",
            "lat": "52.6907",
            "lng": "23.6035",
            "alt": "160",
            "type": "song",
            "url": "\/\/www.xeno-canto.org\/477551",
            "file": "\/\/www.xeno-canto.org\/477551\/download",
            "file-name": "XC477551-190503-Troglodyte mignon@Sacharewo.mp3",
            "sono": {
                "small": "\/\/www.xeno-canto.org\/sounds\/uploaded\/ZWAQHOJFLZ\/ffts\/XC477551-small.png",
                "med": "\/\/www.xeno-canto.org\/sounds\/uploaded\/ZWAQHOJFLZ\/ffts\/XC477551-med.png",
                "large": "\/\/www.xeno-canto.org\/sounds\/uploaded\/ZWAQHOJFLZ\/ffts\/XC477551-large.png",
                "full": "\/\/www.xeno-canto.org\/sounds\/uploaded\/ZWAQHOJFLZ\/ffts\/XC477551-full.png"
            },
            "lic": "\/\/creativecommons.org\/licenses\/by-nc-sa\/4.0\/",
            "q": "A",
            "length": "1:13",
            "time": "08:00",
            "date": "2019-05-03",
            "uploaded": "2019-05-29",
            "also": [
                "Fringilla coelebs"
            ],
            "rmk": "Singing seated or in flight",
            "bird-seen": "yes",
            "playback-used": "no"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the type of created objects

```
return this.http.get<IXenoCantoResponse>(`${this.corsAnywhereUrl}${this.xenoCantoApiBaseUrl}${this.formatSearchTerm(searchTerm)}${this.recordingLength}`)
   .pipe(
      map(o => return new IXenoCantoResponse({
          numRecordings: o.numRecordings,
          numSpecies: o.numSpecies,
          page: o.page,
          numPages: o.numPages,
          recordings: o.recordings.map((element: IVoice, index) => new IVoice({
              id: index + 1,
              url: `${element['sono']['full'].substr(0, this.getPosition(element['sono']['full'], '\/', 6))}${element['file-name']}`
          })
        });
      }))
    );
```

Comment: Hi, that change makes the `element` property of `map((element, index) => new IVoice({` to type IVoice.  So how do I access the properties of the response?  i.e.: `element.sono['full']`

Comment: you need to specify type of your 'element'. But you need to provide more details. From your example I o.recordings have type IVoice[], to element will be IVoice. But, what is element.sono? I think you provide another element type from your API.

Comment: I have pasted the full recordings array in my updated answer.  I map this object to the `IVoice` interface type.  In my original answer I pasted some code which uses a `data.forEach((element, index) => {
  let sub = element.sono['full'].substr(0, this.getPosition(element.sono['full'], '\/', 6));
  urls.push({
    id: index + 1,
    url: `${sub}${element['file-name']}`
  });`

Comment: for angular 8 and below you need to use element['sono']['full']. For Angular 9, you can use element.sono.full. Best practice is to map your json result into a class with same attributes, and instead (element: any) to use (element: your_element_type)

Comment: I'm using Angular 9.  `element.sono.full` does not work.  `element['sono']['full']` does work.  The changed code now looks like `recordings: o.recordings.map((element: IVoice, index) => ({
            id: index,
            url: ``${element['sono']['full'].substr(0, this.getPosition(element['sono']['full'], '\/', 6))}${element['file-name']}`
          }))`  I will mark as an asnwer if you post it...  Thank you

Comment: Is the `return new IXenoCantoResponse` necessary (line 3 of your answer)?  It kicks up an error at my end.  I leave that out...

Comment: more elegant, can be write as: map((element: any) => { return new IXenoCantoResponse(....) };

Comment: Ok, it works without it at my end  And with it it throws up an error...

Comment: Avoid using braces if your code is writed only in 1 or max 2 lines. Else, use braces, code is more readable